# action [cluster:admin/repository/put] is unauthorized for service account...this action is granted by the cluster privileges [manage,all]

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

i'm trying to create a service account token to use it in my code.

```
#generate long service account token
POST /_security/service/elastic/fleet-server/credential/token/token-restore-from-aws
```

the token is generated

```
{
  "created": true,
  "token": {
    "name": "token-restore-from-aws",
    "value": "AAEAAWVsYXN0aWMvZmxlZXQtcXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX10SlJqNjIzT2hGUQ"
  }
}
```

When I try to use it, i got this error 403:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "security_exception",
        "reason" : "action [cluster:admin/repository/put] is unauthorized for service account [elastic/fleet-server], this action is granted by the cluster privileges [manage,all]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "security_exception",
    "reason" : "action [cluster:admin/repository/put] is unauthorized for service account [elastic/fleet-server], this action is granted by the cluster privileges [manage,all]"
  },
  "status" : 403
}
```

I don't really understand what to do.
The url is : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-create-service-token.html

When I check my token priviledges, I have this:

```
{
  "service_account": "elastic/fleet-server",
  "count": 2,
  "tokens": {
    "token-restore-from-aws": {}
  },
  "nodes_credentials": {
    "_nodes": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
    },
    "file_tokens": {
      "cloud-internal": {
        "nodes": [
          "instance-0000000000"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[To use this API, you must have at least the `manage_service_account` cluster privilege.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-create-service-token.html#security-api-create-service-token-prereqs)

You are facing this issue probably because the user you created that token doesn't have `manage_service_account` permissions.

Try to create that token with a superuser.

Check your token privileges

```
GET /_security/service/elastic/fleet-server/credential
```

Comment: it is me that created this token and I have full access on the instance of the elasticsearch.

Comment: i updated the question to add the result of my token privileges.